# How to prevent update mysql field +1 when page is refreshed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, page-refresh

I want to create a sidebar which shows the top 5 articles ordered by clicks. I'm using Codeigniter. I coded simple query.
In the view , i have simple link:

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/article/<?php echo $row['article'];?>"><h2><?php echo $row['particle'];?></h2></a>
```

My model:

```
public function count_views($id)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE article SET views = views +1 WHERE id = '{$id}'";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

My controller:

```
public function article($article_id) {
       $link = $this->quotes_model->get_article($article_id);
       $this->quotes_model->count_views($article_id);
       $views = $this->quotes_model->popular_articles();
       $this->template->set('views', $views);
       $this->template->render();
}
```

When I press article title link(in mysql field views updates +1) it opens a full article. Everything is fine, but if I press refresh, field views updates by +1 again.

If somebody refreshes an open article, mysql should not update views field by +1 again?
P.S sorry for my english language.

Answer (score 0):

You should control it either by using System Ip or by Browser Session id for unique page hits.

Use

```
      session_id();
```

or

```
      $_SERVER
```

variables to get ip address.

Comment: Maybe there is easer way to use javascript or ajax to somehow stop update field when user is trying to refresh page?

Comment: You cannot control user from refreshing the page. It has to be handled in code level in case you only want to capture unique visits of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Add two fields in the table `article`:

```
ip_address -> ip address of the user.

visited_date -> date time
```

Now, when a user opens the article for the first time, it ip gets recorded along with DATE and TIME.

If he/she refreshes the page, check the in the Database, if it does not exist, insert it.

If you want only one visit per user then, do not check date, else check date.

Comment: So I have to add ip_address and visited_date fields. When user will  open an article, i should insert into db his ip and visited date. I don't understand what ti check if he will refresh a page: ip? And one more question? If user will press back button and press article link again, it will add +1? I'm just begginer so i must understand everythink. Thanks for a help.